# Bad performance with regexp_like

Tags: oracle, regexp-like

As title, I'm using the Regexp_like in my oracle SQL queries, but the performance very bad.
I have the following code:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Department, PhoneNumber, Address
FROM DPT.DP_vEmployee --vEmployee is a view
WHERE ID = :p_ID
AND REGEXP_LIKE(upper(Address), upper(:p_Address));
```

I filled and run this query, it returned nearly 6s for 484 records. Then, I tried use LIKE operation for this case:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Department, PhoneNumber, Address
FROM DPT.DP_vEmployee --vEmployee is a view
WHERE ID = :p_ID
AND (upper(address) LIKE upper('%' || :p_address || '%'));
```

In this case, the result returned 1.5s for 484 records. Althought It reduce a lot but it does not make me satisfied.

Is there any other solution to make it faster?

Thank you!

Comment: The solution is to perhaps store your address information as uppercase.  And then, maybe look into using full text search, which might perform better than both your current options.

Comment: It sounds to me like there's a misunderstanding here...  If the value that you are a passing in for `:value~ in both your queries is the same, then it probably isn't a regular expression pattern, and so the regexp_like() call is probably returning "wrong" answers.

Comment: Tim is right, above - but if you _must_ store your address column in mixed case, a function index on `upper(Address)` might be worth it.  (It will help with both = matches and with `like 'value%'` matches).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Now, my DB contain 4925881 records. At Address column, it contain include lowercase and uppercase because of my national text, so I can not uppercase Address column as you say

Comment: Then maybe research full text search options.  Using `LIKE` with wildcards on both ends or using regex is costly, because the whole string has to potentially be scanned.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using "upper" on condition column and pattern, have you try using the regexp_like with "i" case-insensitive matching.